Not able to create Docker-compose Healthcheck that check some lines in the log (stdout)
I am experiencing troubles creating a custom health check for a ASP.NET Core 7 container. My system under test (SUT) consists of 21 containers. When the virtual machine has a huge load, such as when 7 SUTs are deployed in parallel, I experience synchronization problems due to services start querying before the others are ready.
I have identified the root cause of the failure: an API container which does not create the correct tables, but I am not able to check the container's stdout from inside the container in the healthcheck
First of all, I aimed to modify the microservices code as little as possible, so a solution that only involves changes to the Docker layer (Dockerfiles, compose files, etc.) would be ideal.
One of the first solutions I tried was creating a script with the following content:
#!/bin/bash
if docker logs $HOSTNAME 2>&1 | grep -q "Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80"; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi

I copied it into the Docker container:
# Custom health check for RETORCH parallelization
# Copy the health check script
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/checklogs.sh" "/usr/local/bin/checklogs.sh"

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/checklogs.sh"

And configured the compose health check properly:
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "/usr/local/bin/checklogs.sh"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3

The main problem with this approach is that it requires access to the host Docker socket, which is a potential security vulnerability.
The other solution involves checking the container's stdout (log), but I couldn't find any relevant logs in the system directories (/var/logs). Additionally, redirecting the command output to a file in the Dockerfile didn't work and would lead to extra debugging problems in the future.
